# Show that ${\theta}^G \in Irr(G)$ iff $I_G(\theta) = N$, where $N \unlhd G$ and $ \theta \in Irr(N)$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $N \unlhd G$ and $ \theta \in Irr(N)$. Show that ${\theta}^G \in Irr(G)$ iff $I_G(\theta) = N$.

Where $I_G(\theta)$ is the stabilizer of $\theta$ in the action of $G$ on $Irr(N)$ defined by  $\theta^g:N \rightarrow {\mathbb C}$, $\theta^g(x)=\theta(gxg^{-1})$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have thoughts and have tried anything so responders can provide better guidance? Regards

Comment: Nothing useful!

Comment: What's the source? Why are you interested? What do you know? E.g., do you know what all the symbols stand for (don't laugh --- you'd be surprised how many students expect to be able to answer a question when they don't even know what the symbols in it mean)? Do you know what "Irr" means? what a stabilizer is? Give us something to go on.

Comment: Exercise 6.1 of Isaac's book.

Comment: I think your notation is still somewhat weird: $\theta^g$ is a character from $N$ to $G$? Indeed, as the question stands now, there is no indication of the field of the representations?

Comment: It's exactly Isaac's notation!

Comment: Sorry, but I must disagree with you about that notation: how can a character map elements in $N$ to elements in $G$? Is your $G=\mathbb C$? Otherwise there must be an error... And I think you must mean $\theta^g:N\to \mathbb C$? Sorry if I am misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**
**I.**
$<\theta^G,\theta^G>=\Sigma_{t\in T}<\theta^t,\theta>$, where $T$ is the set of double coset representatives with respect to $N$ and $N$, i.e. $G=\bigcup_{t\in T}NtN$ and $1_G\in T$.
**II.**
$\theta^G\in \text{Irr}(G)\iff<\theta^G,\theta^G>=1.$
**III.**
Show that, if $\theta^t\not=\theta,$ then $<\theta^t,\theta>=0$.

Comment: [Mackey's decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory#Mackey_decomposition) is used, in **I.**.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about double coset representatives and do it the Isaacs way: use Theorem(6.11) in your book, which describes the relationship between irreducible characters of the whole group and the inertia group lying over a certain irreducible character in a normal subgroup!

Write $T=I_G(\theta)$. You have to prove that $\theta^G \in Irr(G)$ iff  $T=N$. If $T=N$ then according to (6.11)(a) and taking $\psi=\theta$, the induced character $\theta^G$ is irreducible.

Conversely, assume $\chi := \theta^G \in Irr(G)$, and put $\psi=\theta^T$. Then $\psi \in Irr(T)$ since $\psi^G = (\theta^T)^G = \chi \in Irr(G)$. Since $\theta$ is trivially invariant in $T$, $\psi_N = e\theta$. But $e= [\psi_N,\theta] = [\psi, \theta^T]= 1$, so $\psi(1)=\theta(1)$. By definition $\psi(1)= \theta^T(1)=\theta(1)[T:N]$, whence $[T:N]=1$, that is $T=N$ and we are done.

Comment: why $ψ^G \in Irr(G) $ gives you $ψ$ Irr?

Comment: is it form 6.11 (b) ??

Comment: If $\psi$ would be reducible, say $\psi=\alpha+\beta$, then also $\psi^G=(\alpha+\beta)^G=\alpha^G+\beta^G$ would be reducible. But $\psi^G$ is irreducible, a contradiction.

Comment: thanks would you have the time to discuss some problems from this chapter? 6.2 from isaacs my intuition tells me have to use gallaghers theorem but having trouble on writing this down cause to use gallaghers theorem you must know the existance of an irreducible character in G s.t its restriction is an irreducible character in N.

Comment: maybe invite me to a chat would be really helpfull having trouble with coming up ideas in representation theory..

Comment: Please write me a mail with your questions, to n.s.hekster@gmail.com.

Comment: ok thanks again i just did.